# Search file for multiple keywords in listfile Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, list, search

I have a script which searches file(X) for a keyword however, I want to search file(X) with file(y) which contains multiple keywords.

Source:

```
lines1 = [line1.rstrip('\n') for line1 in open('file(X)')]
print'------'
print lines1
print'------'
Colors = lines1
ColorSelect = 'Brown'
while str.upper(ColorSelect) != "QUIT":
    if (Colors.count(ColorSelect) >= 1):
        print'The color ' + ColorSelect + ' exists in the list!' 
        break
    elif (str.upper(ColorSelect) != "QUIT"):
        print'The list does not contain the color ' + ColorSelect
        break
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Foo\Bar\Python\Test\>C:\python27\python Test.py
------
['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown']
------
The color Brown exists in the list!


Press any key to continue . . .
```

What I want:

```
C:\Users\Foo\Bar\Python\Test\>C:\python27\python Test.py
------
['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown']
------
The color Brown exists in the list!
The color Yellow exists in the list!
The color Red exists in the list!


Press any key to continue . . .
```

I would like `ColorSelect = 'Brown'` to be something like `ColorSelect = file_containing_words_to_search_for.txt` aka[file(Y)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `lines1` from fileX and `linesy` from fileY:

```
common = set(lines1) & set(linesy)

for color in common:
   print 'The color ' + color + ' exists in the list!'
```

e.g

something like below...

```
lines1 = [line1.rstrip('\n') for line1 in open('fileX.txt')]

lines2 = [line2.rstrip('\n') for line2 in open('fileY.txt')]

common = set(lines1) & set(lines2)

for color in common:
   print 'The color ' + color + ' exists in the list!'
```

But if you want to find colours not present then:

```
set_of_lines1 = set(lines1)
set_of_lines2 = set(lines2)
common = set_of_lines1 & set_of_lines2
difference = set_of_lines2 - set_of_lines1

for color in difference:
   print 'The color' + color + 'does not exist in the list'
```

Comment: Is it possible to give an example for the exception error of the color which does not exist like in my edit?